# Replace rule does not match

Tags: replacement

I have the following expression

```
-3 I Ez Re[Ex] + 3 I Ex Re[Ez]
```

And I wish to write this in the form `-3 Re[I Ez Conjugate[Ex]]`. So I have made the rule

```
f_ I x_ Re[y_] - f_ I y_ Re[x_] -> f Real[I x Conjugate[y]]
```

But my expression does not seem to match that expression. What is wrong?

Comment: This thread: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/5cfb8ae645fa5bc1/, should give you an exhaustive answer :)

Comment: @Leonid Thanks. I was starting to feel too good about the day.

Comment: @Daniel Most welcome :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pattern matching with complex numbers is notoriously difficult because `Complex` numbers are atomic yet have non-trivial `FullForm`.

```
{AtomQ[-3 I], FullForm[-3 I]}
```

> ```
> {True,Complex[0,-3]}
> ```

Examining the `FullForm` of your expression, perhaps you want the following.

```
rule = a_Complex*x_*Re[y_] + b_Complex*y_*Re[x_] :>
  Abs[a]*Re[I x Conjugate[y]] /; a == -b;
-3 I Ez Re[Ex] + 3 I Ex Re[Ez] /. rule
```

> ```
> -3 Im[Ex Conjugate[Ez]]
> ```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What is the correct way to add textual Mathematica output, as you have done in your edit?

Comment: I don't know about "correct" but I am putting the output in quote blocks (which just means it starts with `> `  Sometimes I think it looks better to combine code and quote types, which means starting each line with `>` followed by five spaces.  I hoped you wouldn't mind my edit; I guess you don't.

Comment: You can see the raw text of the message at any time by starting to edit it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was hoping someone would edit it so I could see formatted output. I see that R.M. has just added a further edit. I really don't think that either of these actually quite right.  The standard quote block really looks more like a `PrintUsage` cell in Mathematica.  Perhaps, this is discussion for Meta.

Comment: Mark, [it's already there](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2/121).  I am interested to know what you think looks best.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I did quick search on meta for "output" but didn't find that.  I guess I don't have a particular preference, except to say that it's clearly best to set the output aside somehow.