# Applying ReplaceAll to I (imaginary unit)

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, complex

Why does

```
I/.I->-I
```

return

```
 -I
```

but

```
Exp[-I]/.I->-I
```

yields

```
Exp[-I]
```

? As mentioned below the problem seems to be the improper input type of the complex unit: Instead of `I` one should use `Complex[0,1]`. But if this is true, why does the first replacement above work at all? This behavior is inconsistent, or is there a good explanation for this result?

Comment: I get `E^-I` -- seems to work (V10.1 and V9.0.1).

Comment: @MichaelE2: For me the replacement works for E^I, too, but not for Exp[I]

Comment: In 10.1.0 `Exp[I] /. I -> -I` returns `E^-I`.

Comment: @pawel_winzig I got what Mr.Wizard got.  In fact, what you say you get, `Exp[I]`, should not be possible, because `Exp[I]` evaluates to `E^I` automatically.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Well, seems strange but this is what I get as output.

Comment: Then I would say you have another problem, namely that `Exp` does not evaluate properly, which might be connected to the replacement not working.  Does `Exp[x]` return `Exp[x]` or `E^x`?  (Try restarting the kernel, etc., too.)  This is what it looks like for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tzQmP.png

Comment: @MichaelE2: I get the proper transformation from Exp[]-> E^ BUT

Exp[-a I] /. I -> -I
E^(-I a)

however:

Exp[-a x] /. x -> -x
E^(x a)
is evaluated correctly

Comment: That is a different problem than you asked about!  This `Exp[I]/.I->-I` works, but `Exp[-I]/.I->-I` does not.  Just like `Exp[2] /. 2 -> -2` works but `Exp[-2] /. 2 -> -2` does not.

Comment: BTW, have you seen [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate.html)? E.g. `Exp[-a I] /. z_Complex :> Conjugate[z]` and `Conjugate[Exp[-I]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Both replacements have the same form so I thought: Since it works for x it has to work for "I" too. As I understand Bill, the issue is solved with FullForm[]. However, I thought that InputForm[] will reverse the latter after the replacement. This seems not the case, still searching for the solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/replace-rule-does-not-match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23735/discussion-between-pawel-winzig-and-michael-e2).

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46004/replace-every-minus-to-plus-in-expression

Comment: Your addition is incorrect. `I` should not necessarily be entered as `Complex[0,1]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Did you read the other posts? What is then, in your opinion, the mistake? I mean, it's clear that the behavior is inconsistent. But since I'm not the designer of the called function I have no clue what is going on there.

Comment: The question you asked in the original post is not the question you actually have (as stated in your comments). `Exp[I]/.I->-I` works for me in 8, 9, and 10 (and for everybody else too). It seems your problem is actually` Exp[-I] /. I -> -I` which does not get you the result you expect. The point here is that ReplaceAll looks for structural matches in terms of the internal form of the expression. This internal form may differ from the way it is printed. `1-x` for instance, is represented as `Plus[1,Times[-1,x]]`. You have to take this into account when replacing. [continues...]

Comment: [...continued]. In your case (as stated in the comments) you want to replace `-I`, which is represented as `Complex[0,-1]` and `I` as `Complex[0,1]`. So `-I/.I->-1` does nothing as it is equivalent to `Complex[0,-1] /. Complex[0,1]->Complex[0,-1]`. No match, so no replacement.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: I understand, thank you for clarifying this to me. It would be nice if this could be stressed in the Documentation.

Comment: I agree the documentation could be clearer on that (it must be somewhere, but not on the ReplaceAll page). Luckily we have this covered in our popular [Mathematica Pitfalls question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/57).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReplaceAll works on "the structure", not the "pretty printed" form.

```
FullForm[I]
```

gives

```
Complex[0, 1]
```

and

```
I /. Complex[0, 1] -> Complex[0, -1]
```

gives

```
-I
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how to revert FullForm[] afterwards?

Comment: Of course, I understand. However, if I precede in my calculation I have a mixture of "normal form" expressions and FullForm and this generates problems when evaluating scalar products like FullForm[{1, 2, 3}].{1, 2, 3}

Comment: aah, now I understand, I thought it's necessary to have it in FullForm before replacement, thank you!

Comment: Is is difficult to add a reverse procedure?